# How to parse JSON array key name dynamically using shell script jq

Tags: json, jq

I've below JSON, I want to parse all these key names `product, inventory, rating, review` dynamically and put it in the list and iterate the key name one by one.

```
{
    "product": [
        {
            "productID": "123",
            "productName": "test1"
        }
    ],
    "inventory": [
        {
            "id": "12093",
            "name": "adie"
        }
    ],
    "rating": [
        {
            "value": "4",
            "status": "done"
        }
    ],
    "review": [
        {
            "desc": "good",
            "comments": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

After parsing the key name dynamically, I want to form all the key name in a comma separated and assigned to `key_list` variable like below:

```
key_list="product,inventory,rating,review"
```

After that I want to iterate `key_list` in a loop and print them or do something with that value. The desired output would be print the key name one by one in a loop:

```
product
inventory
rating
review
```

**How can we achieve this using shell script jq?**

Comment: Are you saying `key_list` is your _output_ or your _input_? None of this is hard to do in jq (and it's _all_ possible in jq alone -- no need to lean on the shell for any of the logic), but I'm not clear what your desired outcome is. Maybe show desired output, not just your inputs? (You want to iterate over the keys in the list and do _what_ with them?)

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, also, to show what you tried. If you know how to feed your string into jq, and _tried_ to split it on commas but something went wrong... well, knowing what went wrong would let us focus our answers on the specific thing you need to know.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Updated the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To produce a listing of the key names:

```
jq -r 'keys_unsorted[]'
```

To produce a comma-separated string with the key names, you could start with:

```
jq 'keys_unsorted|join(",")'
```